# How to calculate datediff with certain conditions?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table that has a datetime which corresponds to different statuses: clicked, claimed and bought for each user.

I collapse the records of each user and put each datetime corresponding to each status in their own column: clicked_date, claimed_date, and bought_date. I also have a deadline_date.

Now I need another column that calculates the number of days to the deadline date. The new column (number_days) should always subtract deadline_date minus clicked_date. However, if clicked_date is set to "2999-12-31' then it should subtract deadline_date minus claimed_date. If clicked_date is set to "2999-12-31' and claimed_date is set to = '299-12-31' then it should subtract deadline_date minus bought_date. And If clicked_date is set to "2999-12-31' and claimed_date is set to "2999-12-31' and bought_date is set to "2999-12-31' OR deadline_date = '/N' then it should be 0.

[image]

[image]

```
In the examples above,
The first record should be (deadline_date - bought_date)
The second record should be (deadline_date - clicked_date) 
The third record should be 0.
The fourth record should be (deadline_date - claimed_date)
The fifth record should be (deadline_date - claimed_date) 
The sixth record should be (deadline_date - clicked_date)
```

I am having trouble formulating this query. Does anyone know how I can calculate the number of days depending on what is found in each of the three different date columns for clicked, claimed and bought?

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
select 
user,
(array_agg(STATUS) within group(order by UPDATED_AT_DATETIME desc)[0])::varchar as last_status,
   coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'clicked'  THEN UPDATED_AT_DATETIME END),'2999-12-31'::datetime) as clicked_date,
   coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'claimed'   THEN UPDATED_AT_DATETIME END),'2999-12-31'::datetime) as claimed_date,
   coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'bought' THEN ACCOUNT_REWARD_UPDATED_AT_DATETIME END),'2999-12-31'::datetime) as bought_date,
   **case when CLICKED_DATE <> '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000' then DATEDIFF('days', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(clicked_date) ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(DEADLINE_DATETIME))
   when claimed_date <> '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000' then DATEDIFF('days', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(claimed_date) ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(DEADLINE_DATETIME))
   when bought_date <> '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000' then DATEDIFF('days', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(bought_date) ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(DEADLINE_DATETIME))
   END as number_days**
from TBL_A a
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

without running it, this should work:

```
SELECT 
    user,
    FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARITION BY user ORDER BY updated_at_datetime DESC) AS last_status,
    MAX(IFF(status = 'clicked', UPDATED_AT_DATETIME, null)) AS clicked_date,
    MAX(IFF(status = 'claimed', UPDATED_AT_DATETIME, null)) AS claimed_date,
    MAX(IFF(status = 'bought', UPDATED_AT_DATETIME, null)) AS bought_date,
    COALESCE(bought_date, claimed_date, clicked_date, '2999-12-31'::datetime) as date_of_interest,
    DATEDIFF('days', date_of_interest, deadline_datetime) AS number_days
FROM tbl_a AS a
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

you might need to cast the "dates" like you have in your example, if they really are strings already.

the "date_of_interest" can be inlined. There is a small chance the MAX and COALESCE will not play nice, in case, just sub clause it like:

```
SELECT a.*
    COALESCE(bought_date, claimed_date, clicked_date, '2999-12-31'::datetime) as date_of_interest,
    DATEDIFF('days', date_of_interest, deadline_datetime) AS number_days
FROM (
    SELECT 
        user,
        FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARITION BY user ORDER BY updated_at_datetime DESC) AS last_status,
        MAX(IFF(status = 'clicked', UPDATED_AT_DATETIME, null)) AS clicked_date,
        MAX(IFF(status = 'claimed', UPDATED_AT_DATETIME, null)) AS claimed_date,
        MAX(IFF(status = 'bought', UPDATED_AT_DATETIME, null)) AS bought_date
    FROM tbl_a AS a
    GROUP BY 1,2
) AS a;
```